# Ruby - ERROR_Can't convert nil into an exact number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try  to make that, in the controller ...

```
raw_counter_reset_date = REDIS.hget(params[:id], 'overquota_reset_at')
@counter_reset_date = Time.at(raw_counter_reset_date)
```

But when I want lauch application, I have this error :

```
can't convert nil into an exact number
```

I know that `@counter_reset_date = Time.at(1364046539)` works with numbers, but I would that the application take the timestamp date in a database and convert in date on my web-page.

I hope to have been understandable, and thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

this is because `raw_counter_reset_date` is `nil`. convert it to a number (`raw_counter_reset_date.to_i`) or check for `nil`.

Comment: Thank you akonsu, it works ! (I haven't think convert in number)